# Erlang init_per_group terminates gen_server

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, common-test

Common test `init_per_group/2` terminates gen_server when it is started with `gen_server:start_link`.
But it is ok to start server with `gen_server:start`.

`gen_server` can be started with any of these methods (`start` and `start_link`) in `init_per_suite/1` and `init_per_testcase/2`.

Why it is not possible to start gen_server in `init_per_group/2` with `gen_server:start_link`?

Comment: What's the error code when gen_server:start_link failed?

Comment: There is no error. My server traps exit flag.
So in the end of `init_per_group/2` I get in `gen_server:terminate/2` this reason:
`{#Ref<0.0.1.845>,1475, [{server,<0.226.0>},
                              {watchdog,<0.225.0>},
                              {tc_logfile,
                              ... [config data]` 
I use erlang 18.1 with common test v1.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `init_per_group` is run in a separate process, just like each test case, and that process exits with an exit reason that communicates information about success/failure of group initialisation.  From `test_server:run_test_case_eval`:

```
exit({Ref,Time,Value,Loc,Opts}).
```

Since the `gen_server` is linked to the process that runs `init_per_group`, and since the exit reason is not `normal` and the `gen_server` is not trapping exits, the `gen_server` process exits with that same exit reason.

On the other hand, `init_per_testcase` is run in the same process as the test case itself, so this problem does not appear.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. But there still something strange: when gen_server does trap exits it won't receive {'EXIT', ...} message and it will terminate anyway.